# Xamarin.Auth Google not auto close when done login

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I follow guide [enter link description here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/)

I have a issue when I done login my google account it show toast

[image]

And browser not auto close to back my.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In you CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity page replace inside OnCreate.

```
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);          
        global::Android.Net.Uri uri_android = Intent.Data;

        Uri uri_netfx = new Uri(uri_android.ToString());

        // load redirect_url Page
        AuthenticationState.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(uri_netfx);

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        StartActivity(intent);

        this.Finish();

        return;
```

Comment: Worked great. The only other thing I had to do to make this "perfect" is adding global::Xamarin.Auth.CustomTabsConfiguration.CustomTabsClosingMessage = null; to my Android main activity after the Auth init.

Which eliminates that useless toast message

Answer (score 3):

This is the warning message shown in the toast.

We can make it null by adding a piece of code in `MainActivity` just after initializing `Xamarin.Auth`.

```
CustomTabsConfiguration.CustomTabsClosingMessage = null;
```

And for closing the CustomTab login screen and navigating back to your app, set the LaunchMode of your Custom URL activity to SingleTask.

```
LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: In my Xamarin forms app where do I set the LaunchMode for this tab? My MainActivity is already using LaunchMode.SingleTask and the tab is not closing.

Comment: set this in your intent filter activity     [Activity(Label = "GoogleAuthInterceptor", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]

Comment: This does not work properly when I tested it. App resumes focus, but the window is still there in the background when the application close down. LaunchMode is set to SingleTask and ActivityFlags to ClearTop and SingleTop.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me as well in avoiding the toast:
`global::Xamarin.Auth.CustomTabsConfiguration.CustomTabsClosingMessage = null`